# Accidentally revoked access for twitter application

Tags: twitter

I mistakenly clicked the Revoke button beside my site's application (used to push news to twitter).  It's been a while since I originally set this up and I cannot find where to grant access to the application again.

Could someone please point me in the right direction?  I've combed over the dev.twitter page under my application, and looked through my profile.  All I find are references to revoking, not reinstating, application access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the app on https://dev.twitter.com/apps, click on the application name, and on the application details page look for the "my access token" link on the right side.

Answer (score 2):

Twitter now provides Undo Revoke Access Button.......for revoked apps......

Go here https://twitter.com/settings/applications to revoke access and undo revoke access for any app.......